# How to move the blinking cursor in css?

Tags: html, css, cursor

I am working on a [website](http://ferhan.ferohost.com/) (built in HTML/CSS) in which I want to move the blinking cursor towards the right so that its not on the top of icon.

The snippets of HTML and CSS which I have used in order to make a search icon is:

```css
.searchicon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 34.5%;
  top: 22.4%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: red;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-searchicon">
  <input class="form-control search_radius mb-4" type="text">
  <span class="fa fa-search searchicon" aria-hidden="true "></span>
</div>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the HTML/CSS so that I can move the blinking cursor slight towards the right so that the icon is full visible.

At this moment, the blinking cursor is all over icon as seen in the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: there's a jquery custom caret https://github.com/apm1467/jQuery.Custom-Caret/blob/master/demo.gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use padding on the input element to adjust the position of the blinking cursor.

I have edited the code. But in your case all you need to do is add

```
.input-searchicon input{
  padding-left: 35px;
}
```

That will do it. Adjust the position either by increasing or decreasing the padding.

```css
.input-searchicon{
  position: relative;
}
.input-searchicon input{
  padding-left: 35px;
}
.searchicon {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 10px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    color: red;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-searchicon">
        <input class="form-control search_radius mb-4" type="text">
        <span class="fa fa-search searchicon" aria-hidden="true "></span>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks good. One quick question, I am wondering what is the purpose of this ?

`.input-searchicon{
  position: relative;
}`

Comment: When I have mentioned this in my code, it seems to change the position of icon.

Comment: No. just add this and nothing else: `.input-searchicon input{
  padding-left: 35px;
}` . The remaining code is just for display. And here is a good tutorial explaining `position: relative`. https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Comment: Ok, sounds good. I think we do need to add `position:relative` as we are making `.searchicon` as `position:absolute`. 

In my knowledge, we use `position:relative` for parent element which is `.input-searchicon` and `position:absolute` for child element `.searchicon`. 
That's the thumb of rule of we follow, Am I right ?

Comment: That's what I have shown in the code. The concept is simple. When you add `position: absolute` to an element, you will be able tom place it relative to its ancestor with `position: relative`. Hence here we are placing `.searchicon` relative to its parent `.input-searchicon`

Comment: I have accepted your answer and you pushed your code on my [website](http://ferhan.ferohost.com/). Indeed, you have increased my knowledge in CSS. Thanks for that. I have a similar question. 
Suppose if I click on the **calendar icon** both at the start date and end date, I want the calendar popup to appear at the top so that we can select the dates. I am wondering if you can give me a pointer regarding that.

Comment: You need to create a `.calendar` element with `position: absolute` , also placing it according to your requirement by assigning `position: relative` to its parent `.calendar-parent`.  Add `click` event listener on the calendar icon. Anyway, commenting is not perfect for what you are asking. Would be happy to help if you post another question on the concerned problem.

Comment: Sounds good. I have just now posted [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51256634/how-to-make-the-calendar-popup-on-click-of-a-calendar-icon/51256772#51256772). I am wondering if you can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the css of the span element (which is the Search Icon), try to change the style within the input element. Assuming you're using Bootstrap, you could add `pl-1` to adjust the padding-left;

```
 <div class="input-searchicon">
   <input class="form-control search_radius mb-4 pl-4" type="text">
   <span class="fa fa-search searchicon" aria-hidden="true "></span>
 </div>
```

You could visit this [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alvinching28/ods8u5kg/) here to see what the sample output.

Comment: Please recheck. You haven't solved the problem yet in your fiddle.