# Cursor Position of <li> element

Tags: html, css

I have some trouble with the cursor position. As shown in the screenshot below, the cursor is placed at the front of the email address. However, I want it to be in the right of the email address.

What I used is `position:absolute`

[image: ScreenShot]

I checked other solutions, and I tried `float:left`. It leads to the correct cursor position, but the email is disappeared when I click somewhere else. This seems like a problem with chrome 80(It works fine with other browsers). I am wondering if there is other way to achieve the effect like this:

[image: ScreenShot2]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move the blinking cursor in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51237691/how-to-move-the-blinking-cursor-in-css)

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

Comment: @NoahBoegli Not really... In my case, the cursor position should be dynamically determined.

Comment: Is using javascript to dinamally increase the padding something you could do ? Or do you have requirements to not use it ?

Comment: If you could give us some code so that we can help you directly on what you have :)